# Add badge when push received in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I have iOS app written in Swift. I use Parse SDK for push notifications.
I want to add badge to app icon when push is received. **There is problem - I can't add badge from push directly** because there are a lot of users that use previous version of my app. And if I add badge from push - this badge will not disappear because previous app versions don't hide badge after it opened. So badge will be always on icon.

So what I want is to handle push by my app. No matter is it running or not. If push arrives - my app adds badge. So I can I handle push by my app if it is not running?

I know how to add badge with Swift

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 5
```

But how can i do it without opening the app - just when push is received?

Answer (score 1):

When you push the app, you need to send the badge count with it:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "message goes here",
        "sound": "sound.aiff",
        "badge": 5 
    }
}
```

This will change the badge number on the app before it has been opened.

Please note that you cannot change the badge number of an app when it is closed without using notifications to do so.

Comment: The problem is that I have many users that have previous version of my app. And this version is not hiding badges after app is opened. So if I send push with badge - they will always see this badge.

Comment: That's correct. Unless you send a silent push setting the badge number to 0.

Comment: Is it possible for app that is not running to know if push was received?

Comment: When you send a push, it is delivered to the app whether it is running or not. If the app is not running then iOS handles the badge number. If it is, then you need to handle it.

Comment: so is it impossible to handle push by app when app is not running?

Comment: With custom code in the AppDelegate, yes. But if you send a push including a badge number then whatever the current badge number is, it will change to the value stored within the push

Comment: Ok. I can't use push with number because of users with previous app version, so in that case i need to know how can i handle push by my app no matter is it running or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85033/discussion-between-swinny89-and-moonvader).

Comment: Can you update your answer with example - how can app handle push when it is not running??

Comment: That's what my answer is. When the app is not running, iOS uses the badge within the push to show on the icon. When you open the app, just set it back to 0

Comment: I can't set it to be 0 on previous versions of my app. So in new version of my app: I want to edit badge only with my app no matter is it running or not.

Answer (score 0):

Like said in the [Parse docs](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#push-notifications-customizing-your-notifications), you can set badge number setting the `badge` field in the payload with an integer
ex:

```
"data": {
          "alert": "The Mets scored! The game is now tied 1-1.",
          "badge": 5,
          "sound": "default",
          "title": "Mets Score!"
        }
```

or with `Increment` to automatically increment current value in badge count
ex:

```
"data": {
          "alert": "The Mets scored! The game is now tied 1-1.",
          "badge": "Increment",
          "sound": "default",
          "title": "Mets Score!"
        }
```

Comment: The problem is that I have many users that have previous version of my app. And this version is not hiding badges after app is opened. So if I send push with badge - they will always see this badge.

Answer (score 0):

To send push notifications with Parse just use the following code, making sure you change the channel to the correct one:

```
 let push = PFPush()
 push.setChannel("MyChannel")
 push.sendPushInBackground()
```

Then to hide the badges once the user opens the app back up, add the following function to your `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
 func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

    //Reset badge counter to zero
    var currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    if(currentInstallation.badge != 0){
        currentInstallation.badge = 0
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

since Parse SDK keeps it's own badge count separate from iOS app badge count, you need to follow it like this to rest the badge count to zero.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
  if (currentInstallation.badge != 0) {
    currentInstallation.badge = 0;
    [currentInstallation saveEventually];
  }
  // ...
}
```

---

In Swift 2.0,

```
let parseinst: PFInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation();

if (parseinst.badge != 0)
{
     parseinst.badge = 0;
     parseinst.saveEventually()
}
```